# Taking everyday medicine to Australia - do I need documentation for these?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, health, australia

I was planning a trip to Australia next month and was wondering: do I need to do anything/carry permits or prescription for everyday medicine like tylenol (acetaminophen), tums and Imodium?

The [Department of Health website](http://www.health.gov.au/internet/main/publishing.nsf/content/general-guidance-for-travellers-bringing-medicines-to-and-from-australia)

seems intimidating and tempts me not to carry any medicine with me.

Comment: FYI, Australians know *acetaminophen* better as *paracetamol*.

Answer (score 8):

For those particular drugs, **don't worry about it**: acetaminophen, calcium carbonate (Tums) and loperamide (Imodium) are widely available over the counter in Australia itself.

The Therapeutic Goods Administration [page for visitors](https://www.tga.gov.au/entering-australia), and in particular its link to the [entire list of prohibited substances](http://www.health.gov.au/internet/main/publishing.nsf/Content/ocs-treaties-compliance-prohibited-impexp-precursor.htm) (which doesn't contain any of those three), is useful for determining if you need any special permits.

Answer (score 6):

I travel in and out of Australia regularly with prescription medication, as well as over the counter stuff like paracetamol.

As long as the prescription stuff is labelled, they never worry (at most they ask if you have enough for your stay in the country).

I generally declare it anyway, but the over the counter stuff - there's a checkbox on the arrival form for bringing in medicines that 'might be restricted'.  To be safe I just declare everything, but as jpatokal has pointed out, none of the stuff you are bringing is on the list.

Fun fact: 90% of the time, declaring stuff seems to have a shorter line to get out the airport, so this works well for me ;)

Comment: In Melbourne at least the "declare" vs "non declare" is the very last step in the process so either you get out into Australia or sent the other way to discuss what you are declaring so no way (in Melbourne Australia) does declaring make things shorter. I can't talk about other Australian airports. The length of the line should be the last thing you consider when opting to declare things or not.